# Why doesn't odd/even apply to appended element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

IN the following JQuery/JS code --

```
$("a#go-to-videos").click(function(event){
    var hello = 'hello'
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).text().length <= 30) {
    $(this).parent().parent().append($('<li>hello</li>'));
}   else {
    return
}

});

$("ul#odd-even li:odd").addClass("odd")
```

When I click to add a new item, the `$("ul#odd-even li:odd").addClass("odd")` does not apply to it? Why is this so and what is the best workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like the addClass is actually happening onClick. You should add `$("ul#odd-even li:odd").not('.odd').addClass("odd")` inside the click function.